# Multiple OnClickListeners Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have 10 buttons set up which are the answers to ten questions. When a certain button is clicked, I have a switch statement set up in my onClick method shown below. My question is what is the best way to set up the OnClickListeners for all the buttons seeing that I need to pass 2 arrays to the onClick method in order to tell if it is correct or not? Also, I need to return and integer value. Thanks

```
public void onClick(View v, int[] qaarray, int questionorder) {
            int x=0;
            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.imageButton0:
                if(qaarray[0] == questionorder){
                    //correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                if(qaarray[1] == questionorder){
                    // correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                if(qaarray[2] == questionorder){
                    // correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            case R.id.imageButton3:
                if(qaarray[3] == questionorder){
                    // correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            case R.id.imageButton4:
                if(qaarray[4] == questionorder){
                    //correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            case R.id.imageButton5:
                if(qaarray[5] == questionorder){
                    //correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            case R.id.imageButton6:
                if(qaarray[6] == questionorder){
                    //correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            case R.id.imageButton7:
                if(qaarray[7] == questionorder){
                    //correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            case R.id.imageButton8:
                if(qaarray[8] == questionorder){
                    //correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            case R.id.imageButton9:
                if(qaarray[9] == questionorder){
                    //correct
                }else{
                    //incorrect
                }
            break;
            default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown button ID");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) only gives you one parameter, which is the View:

```
void onClick(View v);
```

But you don't have to pass the questions and 'order' to the method to have what you want. One of the technique you can use is the `setTag()` method of View:

```
int[] button = new int[] { R.id.imageButton1, R.id.imageButton2.... };

private class AnswerPair{
    public int questionOrder;
    public int answer;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    for(int i=0; i<NO_OF_BUTTON; i++){
        AnswerPair ans = new AnswerPair();
        ans.questionOrder = i;
        ans.answer = 0; // SET this
        getViewById(button[i]).setTag(ans);
        getViewById(button[i]).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}

public void onClick(View v){
    if (v.getTag() == null) return;

    try{
        AnswerPair answer = (ans)v.getTag();
        // Check answer == question order? index?

    }catch(exception e) return;
}
```

Comment: the setTag() method is rarely used but so useful in cases just like this! As a completion to xandy's answer, you can also set the onClickListeners directly in the XML layout, by using the android:click attribute.

Comment: how can you return information, such as an integer, from the onClick?

Comment: cannot, onClick is a event handler. In the above code, we extracted the information from the View that trigger the event. It's up to your code to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement as many OnClickListeners as you want and assign different listeners for each button.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton)
    b.setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
}

private class MyListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think a lot of people know this already, but there's a shortcut you can use instead of having different instances of onClickListeners and assigning them in code using setOnClickListener(x).

In your button XML, give it the android:onClick property, and assign it a string you like, for example,

```
android:onClick="clickOne"
```

In the activity the sets this xml as its content view, create a method named `clickOne` with a View parameter.

```
public void clickOne(View view)
```

Whatever you place on this method will be executed when you click the button.